# How to implement custom events in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am building a Javascript based application with PHP and mysql in backend.
Because of complexity of code, I want to be able to trigger custom events and do operation whenever that even is captured.

So I came across  [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) and  [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). According to [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/) we can use jQuery triggers as well.

Great? Not Yet. In those documents it [says that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Creating_events) these custom events are not supported by IE.

However, I have used jQuery plugins before which uses custom events and works on IE.

My questions are

1. Are custom events supported by IE?
2. How can I find compatibility across browsers?
3. What is the correct way to use custom events?
4. Are there any jQuery Plugins which caters for custom events ?
5. Are there any NEGATIVE impacts of using custom events?

***Question 1, 2 & 3 are the main concern to ask this question.***

Comment: There is a polyfil on the MDN for CustomEvent for IE. Can you use it?

Comment: I am sorry, but i am a newbie and have neither heard of `polyfil` nor know how to use it. However, I'll definitely google it.

Comment: It is at the same link, you've provided: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

JQuery normalises it's own event structure over the top of the existing browser's implementation for cross-browser consistency.

Essentially you can trigger a custom event on an element and it will JQuery bubble up the event through the DOM tree, triggering the event on each element unless the event stop propagation is called. JQuery 1 supports IE 6 & above and JQuery 2 supports IE 9 & above.

```
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
http://jquery.com/browser-support/
```